# Python argument types did not match c++ signature

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I have c++ code with function:

```
std::string callFunction(std::string funcName, std::string param);
```

I've used `boost/python` to call this function from python code. But when I call this function from python code like:

```
callFunction("hello", "something")
```

it's giving me error:

```
Python argument types in
callFunction(str, str) did not match C++ signature:
callFunction(std::string, std::string)
```

How can I solve this? How can I send std::string from python. (I can't modify c++ files. Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Can't reproduce. Also, there shouldn't be a `main()`.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @karim_g sorry nope. I just made executable and called it from python.
`from subprocess import call`, `call(["my_cpp_app"])`

Comment: `callFunction(str("hello"), str("something"))` could have worked. But I guess this is now fixed with the recent Python versions.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?